# Applescript: path to files in application's Resources

Tags: applications, applescript, macos, path

I'm new to applescript and coding.

I'm trying to make a little Applescript application that plays an audiofile contained in the .app, using:

```
do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of ("/Users/billy/Desktop/test.app/Contents/Resources/Stuff/audio.m4a")
```

The problem is; how can I make the app work on an another mac, without having to change the /username/ manually?

Comment: The two answers below mine and @adayzdone both give you good examples on how to find paths. But when thinking about distributing an app ( and I understand this maybe only for your macs) you need to thing about the whole path of resources like this and not just the User Name. People can choose to store the app anywhere other than what you have hard coded.

Comment: Didn't pick on that, agreed.

Answer (score 2):

```
   set myPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "audio.m4a")

    do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of myPath
```

or

```
set myPath to POSIX path of (path to resource  "audio.m4a" in directory "Stuff")

do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of myPath
```

---

[image]

---

You should look at the libraries in the library window of Script Editor.

In this case **standardAdditions**

[image]

Comment: I got Script error: a resource wasn't found.

Comment: @bbglop whats the actual path you are using. Also how are you adding the resource. You should add it by the side bar in the Applet. And if you change it you may need to overwrite the original or write out a new copy

Comment: @bbglop as you can see from my update it does work?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set pathA to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "test.app/Contents/Resources/Stuff/audio.m4a"
-- or 
set pathB to POSIX path of (path to home folder as text) & "Desktop/test.app/Contents/Resources/Stuff/audio.m4a"

do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of pathA
```

Comment: Although the OP did not mention anything about placement of the app. This does assume that on the other macs the app will always be on the Desktop

Comment: That is why I included the path to home folder so you can adjust the following string.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code :-) but for distributing the app this makes it difficult

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! And since you mentioned, is there a way to make it work regardless if the file is in desktop?

Comment: If the app will be placed in the same location across machines, use pathB and update the string at the end to specify the location. As marke mentions, if you plan to distribute this app to other users who may store it in different places, path to resource is the way to go.